# How I can load google ads without effect page load speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo, web-deployment, google-ads-script

the problem is that when I load ads script like
`<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" defer></script>` 
to my site it makes my site pages loading speed very slow and fails test on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights. the question is , is there any way that can I use google ads and same time page speed is still acceptable ?

Answer (score 0):

I did this once, it loads the gtm-script only when user scrolls. Worked perfect to for pagespeed-insight. Pretty sure u can put it to work with adsbygoogle.js as well

```
var i_a = {
    loaded_gtm: false,
    initGTM: function() {
        $.getScript("https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxx-1", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

            function gtag() {
                dataLayer.push(arguments);
            }
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxx-1', {
                'anonymizeIp': true
            });
        });
    }
}
window.onscroll = function(e) {
    if (!i_a.loaded_gtm) {
        i_a.loaded_gtm = true;
        i_a.initGTM();
    }
};
```